# How do I assign a jinja2 variable value to use later in template?

Tags: flask, jinja2

How do I assign a jinja2 variable value to use later in template ?

```
{% if 'clear' in forcast_list[4] %}
{% img = "sunny.png" %}
{% elif "cloudy" in forcast_list[4] %}
{% img = "sun-cloudy-thunder.png" %}
{% endif %}

<div style="background: right bottom no-repeat url('../static/img/{{img}}')" class="weather-icon-pos">
    <!-- weatehr Icon div -->
</div>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: jinja2 variables are passed from your Flask app. You must specify them in your `render_template()` code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `{% set %}`:

```
{% if 'clear' in forcast_list[4] %}
{% set img = "sunny.png" %}
{% elif "cloudy" in forcast_list[4] %}
{% set img = "sun-cloudy-thunder.png" %}
{% endif %}
```

More information about assignments in jinja2 [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#assignments).

Or simply do the conditionals within python and pass the result to jinja2 template:

```
if 'clear' in forcast_list[4]:
    img = "sunny.png"
elif 'cloudy' in forcast_list[4]:
    img = "sun-cloudy-thunder.png"
...
return render_template('foo.html', img=img)
```

Comment: is there no way to set a variable value inside of jinja itself ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz did a little digging. see my updated answer